# Как полностью скрыть от определенного пользователя часть таблицы?

Tags: google-spreadsheet, google-apps-script

Есть некая таблица в которой есть столбцы "исполнитель" и "стоимость" и куча строк соответственно.
Вопрос в том можно ли в зависимости от того какой указан исполнитель в ячейке скрывать стоимость его услуг от других пользователей(исполнителей)?
Возможно даже скрывать полную строку. Но лучше отдельную ячейку.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Этого сделать нельзя.

В такой системе управления данными, как Гугл Таблица, права назначаются на весь блок данных (файл). Некоторые ограничения, которые мы можем устанавливать внутри Таблицы,например, защищать листы или диапазоны, не являются системными (полными, фатальными, как хотите). Если можно было бы применить ограничения на часть Таблицы для определенного пользователя, то для других пользователей эта часть Таблицы перестала бы существовать, а следовательно для них бы перестала существовать и логика, данные для дальнейших расчетов и построения визуализаций и пр.

Выходов из этой ситуации несколько.

Самый важный и действенный из них - это перестать приписывать магические свойства Таблицам. Люди часто склонны считать что-то не тем, чем оно является. Необходимо четко понимать, что при низком пороге входа обязательно существуют какие-то грабли, которые появятся в самый неподходящий момент.

Другой способ заключается в использовании СУБД. Порог входа уже совершенно иной и требует материальных и трудовых затрат.

Еще один способ занимается поиском других подобных Таблицам систем, в которых существуют дополнительные правила ограничения прав. Я использую такой способ сейчас. Безуспешно.

В контексте текущего вопроса существует следующий способ. Он заключается в применении простого принципа под названием "[Принцип разделения функциональности (в табличных процессорах)](https://gist.github.com/contributorpw/45242e42d50a39b0a957f695cff0dfa4)". Его суть в двух словах: "разделяй и властвуй".